# Error running git in PyCharm after recent update

Tags: git, github, pycharm

I have this "Error Running Git" message when trying to clone from GitHub in PyCharm, it says "cannot run program "/usr/local/bin/git: error=2, no such file or directory". I guess I need to configure "path to git executable"? But I don't know how, I'm very new to using git. And this only occurs lately, after I updated the PyCharm lately.

Updated: After put in the new path, I got an new error:

[image]

Comment: Check if this is the correct path to the git binary on your system.

Comment: I suggest that you google that error message. Also, you should try to run git commands from the command line. This will help you see if the problem is with git itself or with pycharm.

Comment: Error message also mention here https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/254380

Answer (score 8):

This means that the XCode Command Line Tools haven't been installed.  Open and terminal window and type:

xcode-select --install

This will trigger the install and clear up the problem.

(thank you to  @totalhorizon: https://tips.tutorialhorizon.com/2015/10/01/xcrun-error-invalid-active-developer-path-library-developer-commandline-tools-missing-xcrun)

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> then type "git". This will bring you to the git settings. Here you can specify the correct path to the git executable.

[image]

This screenshot is from IntelliJ; you should see something very similar in PyCharm.

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify, I'm on a mac... Do I just pull out the terminal and type "git"?

Comment: Yes I have this window, but I don't know what is the correct path to set.

Comment: Open a terminal and type `which git`. (Assuming that you are on a Unix-like OS.)

Comment: I just tried, but after I put in the new path, it gave me an new error, I put it in the post above.

Answer (score 2):

[Not tested]

Looks like this happens because of bad `xcrun` path. Try this:

1. Find where is `xcrun` located using `which xcrun` and add it to the given path: `ln -s [path from which crun]/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun`

2. Reinstall developer directory manager using `xcode-select --install`.

Answer (score 1):

My IDEs (PyCharm, GoLand and IntelliJ) were working fine. In order to build a source code from GitHub, I had to install Xcode. However, since my company had not updated our Macs to latest OS, (We are on Catalina while the latest is Big Sur), I had to install an older (compatible) version of Xcode.

The installation of older Xcode resulted in overwriting of git to an older version. Running `xcode-select --install` had no effect since the OS itself was older. All I'd get is:

```
mac t2 % sudo xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

Even running `sudo softwareupdate -ia` returned:

```
mac t2 % sudo softwareupdate -ia
Software Update Tool

Finding available software
No updates are available.
```

To work around this, I used `brew` to install `git` for me. Ran, `brew install git` and it updated a whole bunch of things along with installing latest version of `git`. Restarted my IDEs and none of them complained anymore.

Comment: After a recent command line tools update with macOS 11.6 I had the same issue. I used the same workaround (install git through brew) and the error went away. I had experienced this issue before and was only able to remedy it by completely removing Xcode and the command line tools and reinstalling both again.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by the following 3 steps:

1. run in terminal: `xcode-select --install`;
2. download git (https://git-scm.com/download/mac) and install it;
3. set the git path in Pycharm to: `/usr/local/git/bin/git`

Answer (score 0):

```
xcode-select --install
```

Just execute this command in the terminal for MAC OS.
It worked for me, the download and installation took around 10 minutes.